# Escaping user input in the context of a JavaScript parser

Tags: javascript, escaping, code-injection

How does one go about escaping input data that could end up being used as part of a JavaScript expression, or otherwise parsed as JavaScript, in order to mitigate injection attacks with untrusted data?

Trivial examples:

MongoDB

```js
db.foo.find({$where: 'this.value === ' + userInput})
```

DOM

```js
$('<script>')
  .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
  .text('var x = ' + userInput)
  .appendTo('head')
```

I'm trying to understand:

1. The proper way to escape data in the context of the JavaScript interpreter.
2. What sort of trusted JavaScript libraries might exist for this purpose.

Something like this might work:

```js
// Escape non-whitelisted characters with raw hex equivalent.
function escapeJsHex(input) {
  // Replace non-whitelisted characters.
  return input.replace(/[^a-z0-9_]/gi, (char) => {
    // Output double-escaped hex code.
    return String.raw`\x${('0' + char.codePointAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-2)}`
  })
}
```

Usage:

```js
console.log(escapeJsHex('10')) // 10
console.log(escapeJsHex('10; y = 20')) // '10\x3b y \x3d 20'

// Parse simulated legitimate user input.
var userInput = '10'
eval('x = ' + escapeJsHex(userInput)) // -> '10'

// Parse simulated injection attempt.
userInput = '10; y=20'
eval('x = ' + escapeJsHex(userInput)) // SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Seems legit, but would this be sufficient for both server-side and client-side JavaScript escaping? Are there any worrisome caveats? What methods or techniques would be preferable?

Comment: You can't just "escape" away malicious code. If you're going to accept code that will be run in your interpreter, you must trust the source of that code. You can try to sandbox it, but JavaScript is notoriously extremely difficult to sandbox. Of course, if the code is only ever going to be run in a session for the user who supplied it, no big deal; or if you're only going to run it in a limited environment (like a web browser correctly applying the SOP).

Comment: Your first trivial example should actually be `.find({ value: userInput })` and then there is no injection. The second one is on the clientside, so why do you care?

Comment: @JonasW., I'm researching security issues and attack mitigation, and this is something I wanted more clarity on. I totally understand that there are usually preferable ways to handle untrusted data, such as avoiding `$where` altogether, or validating input based on type/shape before using it. However escaping seemed like it might be a worthwhile technique for corner cases, such as user input that is essentially shapeless, e.g,, display names, descriptions, or comments, being used in the context of an expression being parsed as JavaScript.

Comment: As a side note, even `.find({ value: userInput })` is not guaranteed to be free from query manipulation, namely _Query Selector Injection_, since it's possible that `userInput` could be an object: `userInput: {$gte: ""}`, depending on the request body format, or how it's parsed by middleware. It may be necessary to `toString` the input or validate it in some way (`typeof userInput === 'string'`) especially for login routes. https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-preventing-common-vulnerabilities-in-the-m